# Depth first search - isolated nodes

Tags: depth-first-search

I am attempting a depth first search on a dataset which has in excess of 90% of its content as isolated nodes (see node 7 below):

[image]

Is there a way to delete these to cut the dfs time?  Or is it necessary to plug through brute-force?!

Comment: Sounds like a strange DFS if isolated nodes are considered.

Comment: What picture? Did you mean to link to one or put one in the body of your question?

Comment: Sorry - it's in this link.  I was unable to post an image since I'm new.http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2004fa/lectures/lecture14.htm

Comment: If the dataset is static you can prune it prior to the first search, and thus not consider isolated nodes in all of your searches. This only really helps if you are doing more than one search without adding isolated nodes to the data set. If you have to prune each time, it's essentially no change from just terminating each DFS on each isolated node naturally. Have you determined that a significant amount of time is actually being spent searching isolated nodes, though? You should construct a test set by removing the nodes then compare performance.